# Shouldn't there be a Remind_Me_Later kind of button or link ?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I often find interesting questions with code that requires a lot of time to understand, review and suggest improvements. I absolutely want to come back to them when I have spare time to work on those code segments.

I want a button that saves that question for me , and when I login the next time to Code Review it shows those marked questions first so that I am reminded of them.  The Favorite star does not quite do that.

In short I want a Remind_Me_Later kind of functionality, so that I dont miss that question.

Comment: I usually just leave the tab open until I get to it in those cases. If I have too many tabs open, I'll star and close them. It's not ideal, but it's worked for me so far.

Comment: I think its inherent in the nature of this kind of website that a deferral to a later more opportune moment will be the norm. Keeping tabs open and starring a question work but  are clumsy ways of doing something that should be an explicitly visible and immediately accessible functionality

Comment: I don't really like the stars for this purpose either.  I have a folder on my browser Links bar where I bookmark questions I want to visit later.  My bookmarks are synched across all my computers so this works really well for me.

Comment: Just use bookmarks. We are part of StackExchange and they won't build site-specific features for us anytime soon.

Answer (score 8):

I like this idea, as I have the same issue. Perhaps a second favorite option would work - it would add the question to a list, and remove it once you answer the question. I often use the favorite option myself, but I use mainly to get updates on questions I find interesting, but can't answer myself. It's not really useful for marking questions to come back to.